# stretch the background of an div to full width inside container

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website and using a 960 container in the middle, now the only problem is the designer is using different background colors on some `div`s.

So my code for now is:

```
      <div id="content">
<!-- the content needs to 960 on the width only the background need the full width of the page -->
             <div class="whitebackground">
                     <!-- content -->
             </div>

             <div class="bluebackground">
                     <!-- content -->
             </div>
        </div>
```

css:

```
#content {

margin: 0px auto;
min-height: 700px;
position: relative;
width: 960px;

}
.whitebackground{
    width: 100%;
    background:#FFF;
}
.bluebackground{
    width: 100%;
    background:#0054fe;
}
```

Now the problem is the background color of the `div`s is of course only inside the content `div`. Is there some way to get the color of the `div`s going outside of the content `div` and going full width of the page?

Here is the working code http://jsfiddle.net/6cJVV/

Comment: do I see this right?
You want to stretch the background of a div to a size of another div?

Comment: no i would like to stretch the background of an div out side of an other div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the outter div to be full width and then set `width: 960px; margin: 0 auto` to the inner divs.
Take a look at this: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/joe/pen/fEeiy)

Comment: link broken....

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
.object {background-size: 100% 100%;}
```

It is set up as so:

```
.object {background-size: width height;}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Answer (score 0):

I changed my content to a class so I could close it and reopen. My code looks like this now:

```
      <div class="whitebackground">
          <div class="content">

          </div>          
      </div>

      <div class="bluebackground">
             <div class="content">

             </div>       
       </div>
```